Tensor densities in 1 dimensional space
When we consider a 1 dimensional manifold, is a scalar density with weight (-1) the same as a covector?
In particular, in a theory of gravity, if we consider $\sqrt{-g}$, with $g=\det(g_{\mu \nu})$, does $\sqrt{-g}$ transform as a vector when we consider 1 dimensional space. (I think it does, but I'm looking for a bit of validation.)

Let write transformation of $g_{\mu\nu}$:
$$ g_{\acute{\mu}\acute{\nu}} = \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^\acute{\mu}} \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^\acute{\nu}} g_{\mu\nu}$$
Now if we take determinant of about equation we have
$$\acute{g} = J^{2} g \implies \sqrt{-\acute{g}} = J^{1} \sqrt{-g}$$
i.e. $\sqrt{-g}$ is a density scaller with weight 1.
But a covector transform as
$$x_{\acute{\mu}} = \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^\acute{\mu}} x_\mu$$
Note that $\sqrt{-g}$ is a density scaller with weight 1 but $x_\mu$ is a covector (also known as a dual vector or a 1-form) i.e. a linear functional that maps vectors onto real numbers. However in one dimentional spacetime thier transformations are similar but they are different things. Covector is a tensor and differs from density tensor. For example you can not write the equation $x_\mu = \sqrt{-g} $  (this equation can not dimensionally be correct).

In one dimensional spacetime, don't we have $J^1=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\prime\mu}}$, redering the transformation laws equal?

Yes but they are different things

what do you refer to with 'they'? If density scalars with weight 1 transform the same way as vectors (in 1D), then they would be equal by definiton right? Maybe it's in the definition, but often one defines tensors as a collection of numbers that transform in a certain way under changes of coordinates.

Covector is a tensor and differs from density tensor. Can you write the equation $x^\mu = \sqrt{-g}$ in one dimentional spacetime?

I would say yes. In one space time, we could write $x_t= \sqrt{-g_{tt}}$, what would be the problem here?

dimension of $x_t$ is [T] but $\sqrt{-g_{tt}}$ is dimensionless

Does my explanation answer your question?

what if we treat it as a mathematical theory, and everything is unitless, then $x_t$ and $\sqrt{-g_{tt}}$ would have the same unit, right?

I don't have any idea for such mathematical theory, but objects of vector space ($ x_t $) differ from field numbers ($  \sqrt{-g_{tt}} $).
